# When a variable is in scope, it still does not refer to any known column, table, variable, or function

Tags: azure-data-explorer, kusto-explorer

The following query succeeds when we select all (`CTRL` + `A`) run (`F5`) it.

```
let Foo = "foo";

let Bar = (baz: string) {
   print baz;
};

Bar(Foo); // errors here
```

The problem is that the Kusto Explorer lists two issues. Both `Foo` and `Bar` are unknown. How can we introduce the language service to `Foo` and `Bar` so that they are known?.

The query runs...

[image]

The issue list says that "The name 'Bar' does not refer to any known function" and that "The name 'Foo' does not refer to any known column, table, variable or function."

[image]

How can we convince the language service that `Foo` and `Bar` exist?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You simply have to remove the empty lines. The IntelliSense in Kusto Explorer assumes that whatever is between empty lines is the only thing that you're going to run, and that's why it complains about `Foo` and `Bar` on line 7. However, it does let you select text, and then if you click "Run", it will run whatever you selected, and not whatever is between empty lines, but it doesn't affect the IntelliSense.

So if you write this, the IntelliSense won't complain:

```
let Foo = "foo";
let Bar = (baz: string) {
   print baz;
};
Bar(Foo);
```

An empty comment block also works; in some cases the extra spacing aids readability:

```
let Foo = "foo";
//
let Bar = (baz: string) {
   print baz;
};
//
Bar(Foo);
```